# ValueError: The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm working on a blog where i can allow other user upload/post content
Now I'm working on the frontend user post where user can publish their post all fields are working except the image field
after inputting the necessary detail it will show me this ''ValueError: The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.''
Please how can i fix this
my code below

views.py

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    # else:
    #   form = ArticleForm()
    return render(request, 'CreatePost.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from . models import Article

class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # image = forms.ImageField(**kwargs, upload_to='featured_image/%Y/%m/%d/') #this
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = [
        'title',
        'image',
        'slug',
        'author',
        'body',
        'publish',
        'status'
        ]
```

models.py

```
# models
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse


class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager,self).get_queryset().filter(status='published')
# post model
class Article(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('draft', 'Draft'),
    ('published', 'Published'),
    )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='featured_image/%Y/%m/%d/') #this
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()

    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=STATUS_CHOICES,default='draft')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.
    published = PublishedManager() # Our custom manager.

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('Blog:post',args=[self.slug])
```

Comment: Share the HTML `<form>`,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can Imagine, what you don't set in form html Tag the `enctype= "multipart/form-data"`
More Here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files-to-a-form